# How to get all simple product which does not have configurable product

Tags: product, configurable-product, simple-product

i want collection of those product which remain as simple product.

in other world i got all simple product which is include in configurable now i just want those product which does not included in configurable and still alone.

Comment: you mean to say you want to display only the products which are not related with configurable products ??

Comment: yes dh47 you get the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just an adaptation of what [Amit Bera answered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/45284/146).
I just took the code and transformed it into one single query instead of 2.
The idea is to join left the products table with the table that keeps the relation between simple and configurable, and filter only the products that don't have such a relation:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //or just the attributes you need

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => $collection->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')),
    'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
    array('product_id')
);
$collection->getSelect()->where('link_table.product_id IS NULL');
```

now you just need to loop through the collection.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
     //do something with $product
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for short solution . One upvote from me

Answer (score 3):

Magento has simple and configurable product relation in `catalog_product_super_link` table. So you can use advantage from this table.

Basically what you have to do is, ***filter the simple product collection by the product ids present in `catalog_product_super_link` table***

**Step1:** Get list of all simple products by using below code

```
$collectionSimple = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));

$collectionSimple ->getSelect()->join(array(
    'link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),
    'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
    array('product_id')
));

$IdsSimpleCon=$collectionSimple->getAllIds();
```

[image]

**Step2:** Make another product Collection exclude of step one product collection and code

```
$NonConfigurablecollectionSimple = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('nin'=>$cond ));

echo $NonConfigurablecollectionSimple->getSelect();
```

Now, `$NonConfigurablecollectionSimple` would hold all those simple product which does not have a single relationship with configurable products.

Comment: Hey Amit, good answer. Could you please let me know what is the purpose of `catalog_product_super_link`. I never used this table before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the type id to check simple or configurable product. Please refer the below code

```
$product->getTypeId() == "simple"
```

Comment: you did't get my question.
i want only those product which not include in configurable.
your code give all simple product.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete on what [Marius answered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/45290/16127), this works for Grouped products:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //or just the attributes you need

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_link'),
  'link_table.linked_product_id = e.entity_id',
  array('product_id')
);
$collection->getSelect()->where('link_table.product_id IS NULL');
```

now you just need to loop through the collection.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
     //do something with $product
}
```